# How can I implement a function that reduces a list to the minimum set of elements that are repeated in the list?

Tags: python, list, function, set, reduce

How can I implement a function that applied to that list gives me the minimal group of elements, which if repeated n times generates that list?

e.g.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
foo(a)
```

returns  [1,2,3,4]

```
a = [1,1,1,1]
foo(a)
```

returns  [1]

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
foo(a)
```

returns  [1,2,3,4,5,6]

**EDIT**

in other words this function needs to find the germ (see the solution below), a group of elements whose mere repetition generates the list exactly as it is.

A duplicates reduction function would not suffice because, for instance, [1,2,1,1] would become [1,2].

Comment: What should something like `foo([1,2,1])` return?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: @Beginner: the way I read this, it's not just the set of elements; for example, I believe that `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]` would become `[1, 1, 2]`, not `[1, 2]`. However, it would be best if the OP would clarify.

Comment: Yes it is unclear. But if `[1,2,1]` needs to be converted into `[1,1,2]`, isnt that just sorting?

Comment: @Beginner no it's not [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: @jwodder [1,2,1] would just remain as it is.
I want a function that finds "group duplicates". That is, minimal set of elements that, if repeated N times, give rise to the exact list provided as input. 

Could you please remove the "This question may already have an answer here" thing?

Comment: @Josh Caswell exactly, 
e.g. the function to remove duplicate in lists wouldn't work because [1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1] would be reduced to [1,2] and not to [1,2,1,1]

Comment: @jonrsharpe I modified the question, I guess it is clear enough as a good answer was provided. Let me know if you have further suggestions on how to improve it, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```
def findGerm(x):
    for ix in xrange(1, len(x)+1):
        if x == x[:ix]*(len(x)//ix):
            return x[:ix]
```

Then:

```
>>> findGerm([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> findGerm([1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3])
[1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> findGerm([3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1])
[3, 2, 1]
>>> findGerm([1, 2, 1])
[1, 2, 1]
```

Basically it takes beginning chunks of the list and tries multiplying them out to equal the length of the original list.  If the result equals the original list, then you have found the "germ".  In the worst case, it goes all the way to the end of the list, at which point it trivially equals one repetition of itself.

Comment: +1 Kind of inefficient, especially for very long `x`, but clean.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
def foo(subject):
    def test_seq(pattern):
        if len(subject) % len(pattern) != 0: return False   # Quick length check

        for i in range(len(subject) / len(pattern)):
            offset = i * len(pattern)
            sublist = subject[offset:offset+len(pattern)]   # Extract sublist
            if sublist != pattern: return False

        return True                                         # All sublists == pattern

    for i in range(len(subject)):
        pattern = subject[0:(i+1)]
        if test_seq(pattern):
            return pattern

print foo([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4])
print foo([1,1,1,1])
print foo([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

`foo(subject)` generates candidate sequences based on the first *n* elements in `subject` where *n* = 1,2,3,...,`len(subject)`.

Those candidate sequences (`pattern`) are then tested against the subject, as many times as necessary to fit, in `test_seq()`.

Answer (score -2):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def foo(example_list):
    a = OrderedDict()
    for i in example_list:
        a[i] = i
    return [key for key in a.iterkeys()]
```

If pass `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]` as an argument, it returns `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: This often won't work (try `list(set([3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]))`).

Comment: I edited, maybe this one works.

Comment: Its pretty hacky to use a `dict`...And it basically does the same thing as a `set`.

Comment: This actually works!
I don't know what's wrong with the people who downed both question and answer. Probably did not get the question at all.

Comment: It doesn't work.  `foo([1, 2, 1])` returns `[1, 2]`.

Comment: @BrenBarn Isn't it what it is supposed to return? I didn't understand.

Comment: @zamk: The goal is to generate the minimial initial sublist so that repeating that sublist some number of times will give the original list.  There is no way to get `[1, 2, 1]` by repeating `[1, 2]`.  The output for `[1, 2, 1]` should just be `[1, 2, 1]` again since its minimal "germ" is itself.

Comment: I understand. Thanks people! I wish i was not downvoted to hell, I will be more careful with my answers from now on...

Comment: @BrenBarn you are right

Comment: @zamk sorry for you, wrt downvoting look at what happened to my question!!